# Architechture/Best Practice - Best method/pattern to use for dto's in GWT web app

Tags: java, gwt, architecture, dto

I think it's just best to start describing what I'm doing and bring it together at the end for the big question:

I'm building a web app with Google's GWT and encapsulating certain code for re-useability should I develop mobile clients out. So far I have the following projects:

app.core - This has all the data objects (POJO's) like BasketItem, UserAddress etc

app.dao - Data access. This references the above project and has classes like ItemDAO which takes care of item related persisting e.g. void persistItem(BasketItem item, User user)

app.webapp - The GWT webapp. This incorporates the above 2 classes. I use the GWT-RPC between client/server and the server methods call the DAOs to save/retrieve/whatever data
app.server - A RESTful server app which also uses the DAO which will offer a REST-based interface for doing the same data operations to mobile/other clients

Problem: GWT works best at passing data objects between client/server if they implement GWTs IsSerializable (in fact I get issues when I use Serializable). However I don't want to add GWT related jars to the app.core project nor do I want the app.dao etc to rely on IsSerializable. How can I best encapsulate the dto's across the whole app while still using IsSerializable as it works best in GWT. Should I keep extend the core objects in app.webapp and implement IsSerializable?

How would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to keep GWT out of my server code altogether. You mentioned the reason, actually - you're talking about implementing a GWT-RPC interface and then a REST interface that does the same thing.  I decided to just make a REST interface, eschew GWT-RPC and RequestFactory, and use POJ-DTOs.  GWT's `AutoBean` and `RequestBuilder` do a very nice job of moving between Json and Java.  It's just much simpler and cleaner, I think, to avoid the direct connection between client and server (except through your POJO DTOs).  It's also been nice when I want to tweak a small aspect of the operation or add caching or something to just be able to go right in and do it.

Plus, the external documentation for my API is basically just the javadoc from my internal accessor methods!

Comment: I haven't parsed and read HTTP requests since college. Happen to know of any good tutorials on RequestBuilder?

Comment: Sorry, no.  The javadocs are good.  The real thing you need a tutorial for is `AutoBean`, and I think there are a few around.  I learned about it through the `RequestFactory` docs.

Comment: For curiousity sake would I be able to create GWT specific DTOs and extend the app.core ones and implement IsSerializable?

e.g. public class MyDTO extends app.core.dto.MyDTO implements IsSerializable {}

Comment: I'm not sure if that will do what you want - of course you can extend the app.core classes, but I don't know that GWT-RPC will produce a format readable for non-GWT servlets.  `AutoBean` does not require `IsSerializable` - another reason to go with it instead